# Check if user is a fan of my Facebook app

Tags: facebook

How can I check thought the FB Javascript API if the current user is a fan of my app? I need to check this from within the page inserted into the FB's canvas IFRAME, throught the JS SDK...so that I can call a method of a local Flash, and do "something special" for that user.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you can achieve this by using their **[PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)**.

First you're gonna have to query their FQL database. Use the ff query (replace UID with the user's Id and PAGE_ID with your application's Id).

```
'SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid=UID AND page_id=PAGE_ID'
```

So your code might look like this:

```
$client = new Facebook(YOUR_PARAMS_HERE);

$result = $client->api(array(
  'method' => 'fql.query',
  'query'  => 'SELECT uid, page_id, type FROM page_fan WHERE uid=1234 AND page_id=4321',
));
```

This returns an array similar to the ff:

```
array(
  [0] = array(
          [uid] = 1234
          [page_id] = 4321
          [type] = APPLICATION
        )
)
```

FQL page_fan [details here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan).